# Can you open the banner or interstitial ad url in the same app using webview?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, admob

I'm making an app and implementing banner ad in one of its activity. But when I click on the ad, it opens the web page of the ad in the Chrome or the default web browser that I have, But I want the URL of the ad to open in the same app that I'm making using web view. **Is it possible** and if it is possible, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not something AdMob supports. There are a number of reasons why, with privacy and security being the most important.

Comment: Thanks ! I thought to implement it as it could lead to a better experience.

Answer (score 0):

Set a custom URL on Ad click and use deep links([Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links)) to reach requested behavior.

Cons: On click, you will see for a second or two the browser and just then your app implementation.